# Bootstrap 4 Radio dentro de un label e invalid-feedback

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 4 y estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con los radio buttons

El caso, es que necesito que los `input` de tipo `radio` tengan un `id` vacío

Para lo cual, trabajo de la siguiente manera

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="ejemplo" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-label">Con neutro</span>
</label>

<label class="custom-control custom-radio mb-3">
  <input type="radio" value="false" name="ejemplo" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-label">Sin neutro</span>
</label>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Hay un error!</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Mi problema, es que al añadir la clase `is-invalid` a los input, el `div.invalid-feedback` sigue sin mostrarse (en caso de utilizarlo con `id` en el `input` y `label` `for`, funciona correctamente)

Existe alguna manera de hacer esto sin tener que usar JavaScript?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

:valid e :invalid son selectores de las clases CSS.
Esta es la raíz del conflicto.

[CSS :invalid selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_invalid.asp)

Si renombras la clase, se ve perfectamente:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnjkpso4/2/)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, no me refiero a `:invalid`, me refiero a `is-invalid`, clase que bootstrap usa para aplicar el estilo al input, y hacer que la clase `invalid-feedback` sea visible